# PostgreSQL: how to catch exception in a function?

Tags: postgresql, function, exception

I have a table and 3 functions 
fntrans-calls->fntrans2-calls->fntrans3

In this example I have removed call of fntrans3();

After this call

```
SELECT public.fntrans2();
```

the table t2 contains records, ok, it is clear, rollback works to the savepoint inside of function

But when I do call
    SELECT public.fntrans();

the table does not contain any rows and output shows notice about exception in     fntrans;

Why in the 2nd case exception throwed to the 1st function but when I call fntrans2 only it caught inside this function.

```
create table t2(ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, f1 INTeger);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."fntrans" (
)
RETURNS integer AS
$body$
declare d double precision;
BEGIN
raise notice 'fntrans';
  INSERT INTO t2 (f1) VALUES (1);
  INSERT INTO t2 (f1) VALUES (2);
  INSERT INTO t2 (f1) VALUES (3);
  select fntrans2();
  INSERT INTO t2 (f1) VALUES (4);
  RETURN 1;
EXCEPTION  
  WHEN OTHERS THEN 
  BEGIN 
    raise notice 'fntrans exception';
    RETURN 0;
  END;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
VOLATILE
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
SECURITY INVOKER
COST 100;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fntrans2 (
)
RETURNS integer AS
$body$
declare d double precision;
BEGIN
    raise notice 'fntrans2';
    INSERT INTO t2 (f1) VALUES (10);
    INSERT INTO t2 (f1) VALUES (22);
    INSERT INTO t2 (f1) VALUES (30);

    BEGIN
            raise exception 'Oooooppsss 2!';
            INSERT INTO t2 (f1) VALUES (40);
            RETURN 1;
    EXCEPTION   
    WHEN OTHERS THEN RETURN 0;
    END;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fntrans3 (
)
RETURNS integer AS
$body$
declare d double precision;
BEGIN
   raise notice 'fntrans3';

  INSERT INTO t2 (f1) VALUES (100);
  INSERT INTO t2 (f1) VALUES (200);
  INSERT INTO t2 (f1) VALUES (300);
  raise exception 'Oooooppsss 3!';
  INSERT INTO t2 (f1) VALUES (400);
  RETURN 1;
EXCEPTION  
  WHEN OTHERS THEN RETURN 0;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
VOLATILE
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
SECURITY INVOKER
COST 100;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is the line

```
select fntrans2();
```

in `fntrans`. You cannot use `SELECT` without an `INTO` clause in PL/pgSQL.

Without the `EXCEPTION` block you'll get the following message:

```
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "select fntrans2()"
PL/pgSQL function fntrans() line 8 at SQL statement
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function fntrans() line 8 at SQL statement
```

That is pretty self-explanatory.
It also explains why you don't see any results from the function `fntrans2` – it doesn't get called.

You could change the offending line to

```
PERFORM fntrans2();
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is 2 different exceptions, thnx!